# Tensorflow: concat two tensors with shapes [B, None, feat_dim1] and [B, feat_dim2] during graph construction

Tags: tensorflow

As a tensorflow newbie, I'm trying to concatenate two tensor, `t1` and `t2`, together during graph construction. `t1`, `t2` have different ranks: `[B, T, feat_dim1]` and `[B, feat_dim2]`. But `T` can only be known during runtime, so in graph construction the shapes of `t1`, `t2` are actually `[B, None, feat_dim1]` and `[B, feat_dim2]`. What I wanted is to append `t2` to `t1` to get a tensor with the shape: `[B, None, feat1+feat2]`.

The first thing I thought of using is `tf.stack([t2, t2, ...], axis=1)` to expand the rank, but since `T=None` during graph construction, I cannot build the list for `tf.stack()`. I also checked `tf.while_loop` for building the list with `tf.Tensor` object, but couldn't get the gist of using function.

Currently the code I am working on doesn't support eager mode, so could someone give me some hint about how to concatenate `t1` and `t2`? or how to expand `t2` to `[B, T, feat2]` given `T=None` during graph construction? Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add another dimension to tensor `t2`: `(B, feat_dim2) --> (B, 1, feat_dim2)`.
2. Tile tensor `t2` `None` times along the previously added second dimension, where `None` is the dynamic second dimension of tensor `t1`.
3. Concatenate `t1` and `t2` along the last dimension.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

B = 5
feat_dim1 = 3
feat_dim2 = 4

t1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(B, None, feat_dim1)) # [5, None, 3]
t2 = 2.*tf.ones(shape=(B, feat_dim2)) # [5, 4]

def concat_tensors(t1, t2):
    t2 = t2[:, None, :] # 1. `t1`: [5, 4]` --> `[5, 1, 4]`
    tiled = tf.tile(t2, [1, tf.shape(t1)[1], 1])  # 2. `[5, 1, 4]` --> `[5, None, 4]`
    res = tf.concat([t1, tiled], axis=-1) # 3. concatenate `t1`, `t2` --> `[5, None, 7]`
    return res
res = concat_tensors(t1, t2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(res.eval({t1: np.ones((B, 2, feat_dim1))})) 
    # [[[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
    #   [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
    #   [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
    #   [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
    #   [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
    #   [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]]
```